# Debugging App on Iphone and now i get this error: unknown packet reply: "timeout" to environmental package

Tags: iphone, debugging, compilation

I have only started getting this error.

The application works perfectly when working on the iPhone simulator, and there are now errors like the one above.

The application is being put on a 3.0 iPhone if that is any help.

Comment: Adam I'm running into the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: None of the suggestions here worked for me - rebooting everything: computer, device. cleaning and rebuilding. I can't install at all now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you rebooted?  You could try restarting XCode and maybe even power off and back on your iPhone device. If that doesn't work, try rebooting the desktop you're debugging from.

I frequently (well, pretty frequently at least) have weird connectivity issues between XCode and my iPhone and rebooting the phone (power off, back on) will generally solve these.

Comment: Rebooting the iPhone did nothing for me, but rebooting the desktop fixed this issue and another issue I had (couldn't install on Simulator; Simulator showed no apps installed, even Settings).

Answer (score 1):

Check that all paths in your project don't contain '#' simbol.
for example, my project at this path: "/User/alex/Projects/prj_MMH/branches/#19/" causes same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Cleaning the build directory helped.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was that it was running with the wrong build configuration.  Go to the 'Scheme' at the top of the window, click on the '*App*' at the left and Edit Schemas from the menu and select the *'Run Name.App'*.  Under the Info tab, there is the *Build Configuration* dropdown.  It should be set to 'Debug' - I had it set to  'Ad Hoc Distribution'  I think.

The other part which might be needed too, was that under the main project target *'App'* in tab Build Settings  section Code Signing Identity, the *Debug* setting should be set to "Don't Code Sign" and the *'Any iOS SDK'* set to "iPhone Developer"

Answer (score -1):

Is this in the XCode Debugger console?

You could be running the Release version.
Only the Debug build can pipe stdout/stderr back to XCode.

Comment: The issue is that the program is not being run, as the OP states. Here's a sample error output in the console: Running…
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Unknown packet reply: "timeout" to environment packet.
Unknown packet reply: "timeout" to environment packet.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.